# Print string "Image" along with matching pattern in the text file in Python

Tags: python, regex, if-statement, text

I am new to python.My text file has the below information

```
15:50:12 RECID: C642 SORD=000000000 Image=000000001
15:50:12 STEP 2: BUILD ICC KEY MAINTENANCE
15:50:12 RECID: C642 Image=000000000 EORD=000000007
15:50:12 STEP 3: COUNT OF RECORDS UDPATED
02:26:12 CPSE0152E 02.26.13 IS-0001 SS-BSS  SSU-BSS  SE-008965 Image -UE027A0
02:26:12 010000A ABC-HS52                                                 
02:26:12 HS52    DEF-hs52
```

Line 5 (02:26:12) will contain “**SE**-“ and "**Image**"-XXXXXXX” where XXXXXXX=type of **Image** dump as coded.
The next line will have “**ABC**-XXXX” where XXXX = segment name
Line 3 should have “**DEF**-XXXX” . We only need these 3 lines.

"**Image**" keyword can occure so many places but I want to search the "Image" name along with the next line have information  “**ABC-XXXX**” and “**DEF-XXXX**” 
and print the next 2 lines of the text

my output should be

```
02:26:12 CPSE0152E 02.26.13 IS-0001 SS-BSS  SSU-BSS  SE-008965 Image-UE027A0
02:26:12 010000A ABC-HS52                                                 
02:26:12 HS52    DEF-hs52
```

Comment: Avoid regex whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example that will get you what you need.  Assuming your input file is called "input".

```
with open("input", "r") as file:
    output = ""

    for line in file.readlines():
        if "Image" in line:
            output += line
        elif "ABC" in line and "Image" in output:
            output += line
        elif "DEF" in line and "ABC" in output:
            output += line
        else:
            output = ""

    print(output)
```